# temporary files not removed in AKAudioFile.appendedBy

Tags: audiokit

Unless I'm misreading something, it looks like the temporary files created in AKAudioFile.appendedBy when the source file and appended file formats do not match (i.e. convertedFile and convertedAppendFile) are not being removed on return.  The relevant methods are all defined in AKAudioFile+Processing.swift.

Comment: You're probably not missing anything, we'd be happy to accept a Pull Request with this fixed if you want to submit one.